# c# Discord.net How to conver List<string> to List<SocketGuildUser>

Tags: c#, list, bots, discord, discord.net

im having trouble with converting my list type from string to SocketGuildUser as I cannot use cast and SocketGuildUser cannot be used as method. The outcome should take everything stored in "b" as string and convert it into "a" as SocketGuildUser for discord bot.

Code is :

Line 1    `List<string> b = new List<string>();`

Line 2    `List<SocketGuildUser> a = new List<SocketGuildUser>() b;`

Error is on 2nd line :
Error   CS1002  ; expected

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  It's more likely that we will be able to help you if your questions follow the suggestions in [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/.  You might also want to take the [tour].  For this question you're more likely to get a useful answer if you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing an example `string` in the list and how you want to map it to a `SocketGuildUser`.  Where did the strings come from, and what do they contain?

Comment: Is this what you're talking about?  https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/blob/dev/src/Discord.Net.WebSocket/Entities/Users/SocketGuildUser.cs  If so there's no API there to construct or cast a `string` to a `SocketGuildUser`.  We'll definitely need to know the content of the strings to have any chance of helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate through all elements in the string collection, and convert the string into whatever it is that the SocketGuildUser class expects and add it to a new object instance in the SocketGuildUser collection.

```
List<string> b = new List<string>();
List<SocketGuildUser> a = new List<SocketGuildUser>();
foreach (string str in b)
{
    var user = new SocketGuildUser();
    user.Foo = str;
    b.Add(user);
}
```